# Format method in tkinter messagebox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

I would like to return a certain numeric value using the .format() method in Python 3, together with a small calculation in it with the div operator(/).

However the messagebox libraries do not support this feature.

```
        #Remind dilutions
    if self.initial_concentration > (1000):
        messagebox.INFO('Since your dilution is in the lowest range, consider a 1:100 pre-dilution first, so you would have {:2f}').format(answer)
```

Do you know how can I overcome this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
messagebox.INFO('Since ... have {:2f}').format(answer)
#                                     ^
# calling `format` method of the return value of the `INFO(..)`,
#   (not against the formatting string)
# which may not exists; possibly causing AttributeError
```

Above line should be replaced with:

```
messagebox.INFO('Since ... have {:2f}'.format(answer))
```

Answer (score 2):

`format` is an str function, you should use it from the str instead from the INFO.

Solution:

```
 messagebox.INFO('Since your dilution is in the lowest range, consider a 1:100 pre-dilution first, so you would have {:2f}'.format(answer))
```